# Get size of each element returned using map function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to do some operations with the size of some elements in my React application.

What I would usually do is using `refs` But the thing is that my elements are rendered in a map loop like so :

```
listings.map((listing, index) => <div key={index} className={styles.listing}>listing {index}</div>)
```

How can I retrieve the size of each elements rendered using this `Array.map` ?

(I need the size to do some computation to get an appropriate "max-height" value for each element).

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Until the elements are actually in the DOM, it's not possible to get the size (unless you're fixing the size via the styles, but then you wouldn't have the problem in the first place).

Comment: Create a component that returns the div and holds all the sizing logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can create a series of useRef and assign them to element

```
const refs = useRef(listings.map(React.createRef))

listings.map((listing, index) => <div key={index} className={styles.listing} ref={refs.current[index]}>listing {index}</div>)
```

Comment: I didn't know this was possible ! How can I now apply my height in my `style` props ? I tried to store all the heights in a state using `useEffect` but at the first render they are all null...

Comment: add refs in useEffect array to detect ref changes